# downloading programmatically an image generated with html/php

Tags: php, html, automation

there is this image generated by - what it looks like- html, and I want to download the image programmatically, I first tried wget but got ERROR 500, downloading the image using a browser and mouse right click worked fine. 
Is there a way to do this programmatically ?

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none;background-position: 0px 0px, 10px 10px;background-size: 20px 20px;background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #eee 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #eee 75%, #eee 100%),linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 50%, white 25%, white 75%, #eee 75%, #eee 100%);" src="https://example.com/image.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function can be used to save the file on the server:

```
<?php echo file_put_contents("image_script.php","output_to_file.jpg"); ?>
```

Comment: but how can I do that programaticaly, as I can't download the page's source with wget for example.

Comment: right now I'm considering using selenium and simulate a right mouse click

Comment: Do you have access to the backend of the server?Do you mind posting an URL to the image?

Comment: No, I don't have access to the backend, this image changes everytime it loads*.    I'm sorry I can't share the url.(I don't think they would like people downloading these images this way)

Comment: Oh, it's a different story then.